# Aliasing a route causes rails to expect paths that don't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, view, routes, alias

ok here's some code:

```
prompt>rails my_app
prompt>cd my_app
prompt>script/generate scaffold service_type title:string time_allotment:integer
prompt>rake db:migrate
```

then edit these files to look like this:

```
#routes.rb:
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :services, :controller => :service_types
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

which produces these routes:

```
prompt>rake routes
    services GET    /services(.:format)                {:controller=>"service_types", :action=>"index"}
             POST   /services(.:format)                {:controller=>"service_types", :action=>"create"}
 new_service GET    /services/new(.:format)            {:controller=>"service_types", :action=>"new"}
edit_service GET    /services/:id/edit(.:format)       {:controller=>"service_types", :action=>"edit"}
     service GET    /services/:id(.:format)            {:controller=>"service_types", :action=>"show"}
             PUT    /services/:id(.:format)            {:controller=>"service_types", :action=>"update"}
             DELETE /services/:id(.:format)            {:controller=>"service_types", :action=>"destroy"}
                    /:controller/:action/:id           
                    /:controller/:action/:id(.:format)
```

_

```
 #my_app/app/views/service_types/index.html.erb
 <h1>Listing service_types</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Time allotment</th>
  </tr>

<% @service_types.each do |service_type| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=h service_type.title %></td>
    <td><%=h service_type.time_allotment %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', service_type %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_service_path(service_type) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', service_type, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New service_type', new_service_path %>
```

-

```
#my_app/app/views/service_types/new.html.erb
<h1>New service_type</h1>

<% form_for(@service_type) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :time_allotment %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :time_allotment %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', services_path %>
```

when you try to access http://localhost:3000/services/new you get the following error:

```
undefined method `service_types_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0xb7199a80>
```

Extracted source (around line #3):

```
1: <h1>New service_type</h1>
2: 
3: <% form_for(@service_type) do |f| %>
4:   <%= f.error_messages %>
5: 
6:   <p>
```

Application Trace:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/polymorphic_routes.rb:107:in `__send__'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/polymorphic_routes.rb:107:in `polymorphic_url'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/polymorphic_routes.rb:114:in `polymorphic_path'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:298:in `apply_form_for_options!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:277:in `form_for'
/home/aaron/NetBeansProjects/my_app/app/views/service_types/new.html.erb:3:in `_run_erb_app47views47service_types47new46html46erb'
/home/aaron/NetBeansProjects/my_app/app/controllers/service_types_controller.rb:29:in `new'
```

Anyone have any idea why it believes that service_types_path is in my code when it's not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% form_for(@service_type) do |f| %>
```

remove with

```
<% form_for(@service_type, :url => services_path, :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: And how to guess a method in _form.html.erb? "create" should do post to /create, while "update" should do put to /update.

Comment: @philpirozhkov, did you read a question? Where did you find somethiing  about `_form.html.erb`? Topic author asked about `new.html.erb` template.